# Firebase doesn't let me get authentication with other networks - Firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After upgrading Firebase to the new version I get a odd behavior.

When logged in, into my firebase with android studio emulator, every thing works until I change my connection provider, and I'll get  `Firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor` message when trying to login.

**UPDATE**

Trying same thing with the old Firebase database now, and I see that I've the same problem and not able to login, but without the message. Will start a new post about that and leave this as It is.
[Authentication with old and new Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423465/authentication-with-old-and-new-firebase)

> 05-23 12:37:11.386 2792-2901/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar
>   E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find
>   class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rasmusjosefsson.rjcar-1/lib/x86_64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

**SDK Tools - Google Play service (version 30)**

**SDK Tools - Google Repository (version 26)**

**Android Studio 2.1.1**

**Google Play service - 9.0.80**

**google-service.json - (oauth_client id, api key, other_platform_oauth_client... and more)**

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

**

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'


    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.12'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'


    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```